# 'new' expression, whose target lacks a construc signature, implicitly has an 'any' type

Tags: android, reactjs, ionic-framework, push-notification, capacitor

I have a file **notifications.service.ts** which requests a token for push notifications:

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { PushNotifications, PushNotificationSchema, PushNotificationToken } from '@capacitor/push-notifications';
import { Plugins } from '@capacitor/core';
const { Capacitor } = Plugins;

export function NotificationsService() {
  useEffect(() => {
    initPush();
  }, []);

  function initPush() {
    if (Capacitor.getPlatform() !== 'web') {
      registerPush();
    }
  }

  function registerPush() {
    PushNotifications.requestPermissions().then((permission) => {
      if (permission.receive === 'granted') {
        PushNotifications.register();
      } else {
        // If permission is not granted
      }
    });

    PushNotifications.addListener('registration', (token: PushNotificationToken) => {
      console.log(token.value);
    });

    PushNotifications.addListener('registrationError', (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });

    PushNotifications.addListener('pushNotificationReceived', (notification: PushNotificationSchema) => {
      console.log(notification);
    });
  }

  return null; // or you can return a JSX component if needed
}
```

But in **App.tsx** an error appears when I try to initialise it:

```
import { NotificationsService } from './services/notification.service'; 
...
useEffect(() => {
    const pushNotifications = new NotificationsService();
    pushNotifications.initPush();
  }, []);
```

Error:
'new' expression, whose target lacks a construct signature, implicitly has an 'any' type.

Thank you for your time and I would grateful for your help :)

As I understand it, the point is for this expression to be of type any???

```
export function NotificationsService(this:any) {
  useEffect(() => {
    initPush();
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

you aren't trying to create an instance of NotificationsService function using the **new** keyword . but you shouldn't use it like this . just remove **new**

**change :**

```
 const pushNotifications = new NotificationsService();
```

**to  :**

```
 const pushNotifications = NotificationsService();
```